# Вычисление длины вектора на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список, например:

```
["2 -1 5 4"]
```

Это координаты точек вектора, соответственно x1,y1,x2,y2. Нужно найти длину вектора образованного этими точками.

Подскажите более "питоновский" способ решения такой задачи. Как правильно вырвать значения из этой строки, чтобы потом всё посчитать?

На то, что в списке просто одна строка, не обращайте внимания, так и должно быть. :)

Comment: я правильно понимаю - у вас координаты строго двух точек на плоскости заданы в виде списка, состоящего из одной строки?

Comment: Дан файл. В каждой строке указаны 4 числа - это координаты точек. Строк несколько. Я читаю файл с помощью readlines() и получаю список строк, очищаю его от "\n" и получаю чистый список со строками, в которых записаны эти координаты.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример файла как есть (скажем, 3-5 строк)?

Comment: Ну пример очень простой)

Comment: Просто txt файл, одна строка - 4 цифры

Comment: у вас задача практическая или академическая?

Comment: Практика на курсах

Comment: для таких задач идеально подходят модули pandas/numpy/scipy - если задача практическая, то это решается в 2-3 строки при помощи указанных модулей

Comment: `intlist = [int(x) for x in strlist[i].split()]`

Answer (score 4):

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

# читаем файл в pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['x1','y1','x2','y2'])
```

получили:

```
In [373]: df
Out[373]:
   x1  y1  x2  y2
0   2  -1   5   4
1   1   2   3   4
2  10   3  18   1
```

считаем расстояния между точками для каждой строки:

```
df = df.eval("dist = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)**0.5")
```

результат:

```
In [375]: df
Out[375]:
   x1  y1  x2  y2      dist
0   2  -1   5   4  5.830952
1   1   2   3   4  2.828427
2  10   3  18   1  8.246211
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно при помощи регулярных выражений сделать:

```
import re
map(int, re.findall(r'\d+|-\d+', l[0])) # вернёт [2, -1, 5, 4]
```